# How to extract comments in scala 3 source files by using a tasty inspector

Tags: scala, scala-macros, scala-3, tasty

Say I am parsing the tasty file of some scala source file like this source file:

```scala
/** Some comments
  */
trait LsFunctions:
...
```

I would like to extract the "Some comments" comment and ideally associate it with trait LsFunctions.

At the moment my code looks like this:

```scala
import codegen.tastyextractor.model.{EMethod, EPackage, EParam, EType}
import dotty.tools.dotc.ast.Trees.*

import scala.quoted.*
import scala.tasty.inspector.*

class StructureExtractorInspector extends Inspector:
  override def inspect(using Quotes)(tastys: List[Tasty[quotes.type]]): Unit =
    for tasty <- tastys do
      val ctx                                      = scala.quoted.quotes.asInstanceOf[scala.quoted.runtime.impl.QuotesImpl].ctx
      given dotty.tools.dotc.core.Contexts.Context = ctx
      tasty.ast match {
        case PackageDef(pid, stats) =>
          val types = stats.collect { case TypeDef(typeName, Template(constr, parentsOrDerived, self, preBody: List[_])) =>
...
```

But I can't find any method or so that can give me the comments. Running scalac with tasty-inspector I see that the tasty file retains the comments.

Comment: Maybe [parsing and retrieving data with the TASTy inspector](https://www.virtuslab.com/blog/mine-scala-3-compiler-metadata-tasty-files/#3-parsing-and-retrieving-data-with-the-tasty-inspector) is what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks @GastónSchabas , I copied the code from that repo and with a bit of tweaking managed to get the info I wanted from the tasty files.

I am still confused with the AST, the runtime classes I get are i.e. Trees.PackageDef but I have to use PackageClause (which is declared as a type but also has different structure, not sure how this is even possible). IntelliJ is not helping much so I am editing these with the help of vscode too. Anyway the important for me here was to do all the traversing via TreeAccumulator

Comment: It's not clear me if you were able to solve the issue. In case of it did, please add an answer with details of how you solve your problem (knowing that there is no much docs, it could be helpful in a future). If you couldn't solve your problem, feel free to edit your post and add more details about it. If you have a new problem, create a new post detailing the new issue

Comment: Yes I was able to read the scaladocs, thanks. I've posted a sample code below.

Answer (score 1):

I used the link provided by Gaston in the comments above and copied some code and finally managed to extract the comments from the tasty files. Here is the solution for reference. In my case I had to use several TreeAccumulators but a simplified version of my code is below:

```scala
import scala.quoted.*
import scala.tasty.inspector.*

// something to collect the results including the scalaDocs
case class EType(name: String, scalaDocs: Option[String])

class StructureExtractorInspector extends Inspector:

  override def inspect(using Quotes)(tastys: List[Tasty[quotes.type]]): Unit =
    import quotes.reflect.*


    object TypeTraverser extends TreeAccumulator[List[EType]]:
      def foldTree(existing: List[EType], tree: Tree)(owner: Symbol): List[EType] =
        val r = tree match
          case c: ClassDef =>
            val t = EType(c.name, c.symbol.docstring)
            List(t)
          case _           =>
            Nil
        foldOverTree(existing ++ r, tree)(owner)
    end TypeTraverser

    for tasty <- tastys do
      val tree = tasty.ast
      val results = TypeTraverser.foldTree(Nil, tree)(tree.symbol)
      ... do something with the results ...
```

and finally to run it:

```
val inspector = new StructureExtractorInspector
TastyInspector.inspectAllTastyFiles(Nil, jars, Nil)(inspector)
```